# Batch going to a label every 10 seconds while other commands are running

Tags: batch-file

I'm making a (Very Unpretty) Batch Chatroom, and it updates by uploading and downloading a file to an ftp server. Every time you enter a message, using the SET command, it echo's whatever was typed into log.dat, uploads log.dat,  goes to :Chatloop , and gets log.dat from the ftp server. How do I, while still being able to enter chat, make it goto :Chatloop every 10 seconds unless you do it manually with the enter key?

Comment: One possible solution would be to have two separate windows (obviously not ideal), one for tailing the text file, and one for sending messages.

Comment: Non-blocking input is surprisingly possible to do in batch, but it's not easy.  I'm not sure how much code a minimal example would be.  You can try to figure it out from dbenham's awesome snake.bat game: http://www.dostips.com/forum/viewtopic.php?f=3&t=4741 or perhaps batch `tee`: http://ss64.org/viewtopic.php?id=1828